# How do I know when to use V+to+present simple, v+ gerund, or v+to+gerund?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

How do I know when to use V+to+present simple, v+ gerund, or v+to+gerund?

I look forward seeing you.

I look forward to see you.

I look forward to hearing from you.

I look forward to hear from you.

I like to skating.

I like to skate.

I like skating.

Are there any differences? Which one is correct and incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083)   P.S. “to see” and “to skate” are not “to” + present simple; they are infinitives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive)

Comment: to look forward is an idiom and always takes ing. You memorize it.

Comment: You have to learn them one by one. This text will help you learn them. https://www.tacoma.uw.edu/sites/default/files/2021-05/accs_grammar-complementation-parts-a_b_c_rev2016.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That is a very broad subject. try and to find online what are the differences between a to-infinitive phrase vs gerunds.

but here are some rules of thumb:

1. after a preposition only a gerund may follow and and not a to-infinitive. (unless that preposition is part of a phrasal verb).
2. the verb that precedes the phrase **usually** dictates what phrase would follow.
   *want* as in: I *want* to dance.

   or

   deny as in: he *denied* committing the crime
3. some verbs may be followed by both and thus change their meanings.

Remember as in:

- I remember going outside (an action that had already happened)
- I remember to go outside (an action to do in the future)

Comment: I want to emphasise the point that it is mostly _a property of the particular headword_ (which could be a noun or adjective, not only a verb). Their subcategorisation frames are as much a part of their dictionary entry  as their spelling.

Comment: https://www.tacoma.uw.edu/sites/default/files/2021-05/accs_grammar-complementation-parts-a_b_c_rev2016.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Correct:

I look forward to seeing you

I look forward to hearing from you

I like to skate  OR  I like skating

Sorry I can’t tell you the reason why, just what sounds right to me (native speaker).